# Пофиксить вывод данных в консоли Visual Studio Code

Tags: консоль, visual-studio-code, cmd

в обычной консоли лог оутпута выдаётся нормальный не съезжает ничего никуда, но когда я пытаюсь запустить это через vs code, то там всё съезжает, новый текст печатается поверх старого а старый остаётся внизу, как это можно пофиксить? Я попытался добавить эти параметры в настройки консоли, но ничего не изменилось.

```
"terminal.integrated.scrollback": 10000,
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Consolas"
```

Нормальный вывод запуска с обычной консоли
[image: Нормальный вывод]

Вывод с запуска в консоли Vs Code
[image: Вывод в консоли Vs Code]

Comment: Какой у вас тип терминала в VsCode? Похоже, что Command Prompt aka `cmd`. Поменяйте терминал на Power Shell, изменится ли вывод?

Comment: @PakUula Да терминал cmd, стоял он так же и на Power Shell, ничего не поменялось

Comment: @Lumo попробуй терминал Bash, это не решение текушей проблемы но как алтернатива згадится, в Bash такого не наблюдал.

Comment: @Armen Bash от гита который? Или какой именно? В стандартных профилях его просто нет

Comment: @Lumo да тот что от гита

Comment: @Armen она не особо подходит( нужно запускать батники эксешники и тд, там некоторые пути и команды ломаются

Comment: @Lumo тогда без понятия как помочь(, у сомого было это баролся запуском нового терминала либо очисткой, потом перешел на bash.